# Skip compilation of all Googletest unit test classes

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c-preprocessor, googletest

My project features many unit tests based on Googletest, i.e. classes inheriting from `testing::Test`. Each source file folder in the project has a subfolder `test/` where these classes are located.

I would like users to be able to remove the dependency on Googletest. What is the easiest way to do this? Does Googletest provide some support?

One possible solution is to introduce a preprocessor variable `NOUNITTESTS`. When this is defined, all source depending on Googletest is skipped during compilation. But can I avoid going through all the test classes and surrounding them with `#ifndef NOUNITTESTS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why users depend on your project unit tests.

Normally when you compile your binary or library you have targets to make that binary and completely different target to compile the unit tests. This way your users will never depend on your unit tests.

If you work with makefiles - just make a separate target for unit tests.

If you use Visual Studio - just make a separate project within solution for unit tests.

Unit test are not part of the released product anyway. For example, your project might have targets like `clean`, `compile`, `install`, `test`. Unless users run `test` target there will no be dependency on `GTest`.